# Query array of objects in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

How can I query this data with name, what should I write in where clause?

```
{a: [{name: 'test'}, {name: 'test2'}]}
```

The example bellow is for first element only. I would like to have for every index.

```
a: {
       0: {
            name: value
        },
 },
```

Comment: The question is not straightforward, do you want to filter the result data by name?
 
Or do you have a column in the database which an array of JSON?

Comment: I have a column in my DB table which type is JSONB. I call it 'a' above.

Answer (score 0):

Query by name using pure SQL.

```
await sequelize.query(
  SELECT
   *
  FROM 
    table_name
  WHERE
     a->>'name' = 'something';
  );
```

Converting this to sequelize functions should be something equivalent to this query.

```
Model.findAll<Model>({
  where: { 'a': { name: 'something' } }
});
```

*EDIT AFTER THE COMMENT*:

I couldn’t find sequelize function for jsonb_array_elements, so I hope a pure SQL query can help.

```
await sequelize.query(
SELECT * FROM table_name, jsonb_array_elements(table_name.jsonb_column_name) with ordinality arr(item_object)
WHERE item_object->>'name' = 'test';
)

// jsonb_column_name is the same as a
```

Comment: The point here is that 'a' is array (array of objects) and not object. Your sequelize function considers 'a' as object. Thanks.

Comment: @Mihran, I added a pure SQL version of how to do that, and I hope it may help

Comment: Thanks a lot, it may work just I will try something in the scope of Sequelize without a query.